# Save the values of dynamically loaded textboxes into appropiate sections

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

Below is my scenario, Hope i get an answer as I am struggling with this for the past two days.

Suppose I have a class as below

```
public partial class School{

   public TransmissionHeader SchoolDetails;

    private List<student details> invoice = new List<student details>();
    public List<StudentDetails> StudentDetails
    {
        get { return student details; }
        set { student details= value; }
    }

    }
public partial class StudentDetails{

    public Studentheader Studentheader;
    private List<Marks> marks= new List<Marks>();
    public List<Marks> Marks
    {
        get { return marks; }
        set { marks= value; }
    }
    private List<activitydetails> activitydetails= new List<activitydetails>();
    public List<ActivityDetails> ActivityDetails
    {
        get { return activitydetails; }
        set { activitydetails= value; }
    }
 public partial class ActivityDetails
 {
     public string Activity number;
     public sports Sports;
 }
 public partial class Sports
 {
    public string Activity number;
    public string Sportstype;
    public string SportsLocation;
 }
```

There is a drop down on the page , if the value in the dropdownlist is changed there are some textboxes that are loaded dynamically on the page (server side coding).

Suppose Sportstype is a textbox that is loaded dynamically on the page, how do I capture the value that is entered by the user and save it in `Sports--Sportstype`.

Hope I am making sense.Thanks all.

Comment: You aren't making too much sense. (1) What are you using asp.net? mvc (I assumed asp.net from server/page) (2) what about your html, how is the drop down even defined?

Comment: asp.net ,the datasource for the drop down values is a sharepoint list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the textbox is created.

If the code that creates the textbox can assign it a unique name, then it can be found with the FindControl method, or just by name (`sportsTextBox3`).

If it is part of an ordered collection (like a repeater, for example), then it might be accessible through an indexer (`sportCollection[sportIndex].sportsTextBox`).

If it is in a DataGrid, then you could locate the control by iterating through its `Controls` property (and the `Controls` properties of the children, recursively, if necessary).

**UPDATE**

Something like this?

```
private Sports GetSelectedSports()
{
    Sports sports = new Sports();
    sports.Sportstype = sportsTypeTextBox.Text;
    return sports;
}
```

Comment: I am able to locate the text box with its id, however what I dont understand is how do I make sure that value entered by the user in the textbox is saved in sportstype. Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: foreach (Control ctrl in DynPanel.Controls) { if (ctrl is TextBox) { string id = ctrl.ID; after getting id of the text box , how do I get the text entered by the user in the textbox of that id ....